# Accessing embedded type fields through interface

Tags: reflection, go, struct, interface, embedding

It seems like I missed something important but I can not figure out what it is. I use reflect to access embedded type fields through an interface. The problem I have is that according to `runtime/pprof` it eats up a lot of CPU. I do not like to implement Setter and Getter methods on all Vehicles so is there a better way of doing this?

Simplified sample:

```
package main

import(
    "reflect"
    "fmt"
)

// the "contract" is that all vehicles have an embedded Engine
type Vehicle interface {}

type Engine struct {
    Power float64
    Cubic float64
}

type Car struct {
    Engine
    Weight float64
    TopSpeed float64
}

// more Vehicles with Engines here...

func EngineCheck(v Vehicle) {
    // this does not work:
    //power := v.Power
    // reflection works but eats up a lot of CPU:
    power := reflect.ValueOf(v).Elem().FieldByName("Power").Interface().(float64)
    fmt.Println(power)
}

func main() {
    c1 := &Car{Engine{120.0, 1.2}, 1.5, 250}

    EngineCheck(c1)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) if you know the exact type which is fast, and only revert to reflection if that fails.

For example:

```
func EngineCheck(v Vehicle) {
    var power float64
    if eng, ok := v.(*Car); ok {
        power = eng.Power
    } else {
        power = reflect.ValueOf(v).Elem().FieldByName("Power").Interface().(float64)
    }
    fmt.Println(power)
}
```

Note that the types `Car` and `*Car` are different, and the above example would only "skip" the reflection part if the value you pass is indeed a pointer: `*Car`.

If there are multiple possible "acceptable" types, you could use a [type switch](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Switch_statements). For example if you pass a `Car` or `*Car`, you can get the `Power` value from both. Also if `Engine` or `*Engine` would be passed, the same thing applies.

```
func EngineCheck(v Vehicle) {
    var power float64
    switch i := v.(type) {
    case *Car:
        power = i.Power
    case Car:
        power = i.Power
    case *Engine:
        power = i.Power
    case Engine:
        power = i.Power
    default:
        power = reflect.ValueOf(v).Elem().FieldByName("Power").Interface().(float64)
    }
    fmt.Println(power)
}
```

But the idiomatic solution would still be to add a getter function to `Vehicle`:

```
type Vehicle interface {
    GetPower() float64
}
```

Note that you do not have to implement `GetPower()` everywhere. If you implement it at the `Engine`:

```
func (e Engine) GetPower() float64 {
    return e.Power
}
```

And you embed `Engine` into `Car` (as you did), your `Car` type will automatically have this `GetPower()` method (promoted) in its [method set](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets) and thus it will automatically implement `Vehicle`. And then your `EngineCheck()` function would be as simple as:

```
func EngineCheck(v Vehicle) {
    fmt.Println(v.GetPower())
}
```

Try all these 3 variants on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/_obSaCL_Sj).

Comment: I like the idiomatic part of your answer. It is clean an straight forward. Thank you Icza!